# Compare operation using NEON Instructions

Tags: arm, simd, neon

I have the below code

```
if ( i < 0 ) {
  i = i + 1
}
```

Using NEON vectorized instructions I need to perform the above. How do I compare a NEON register value with 0 and perform the above calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need many instructions for this. A single vsra instruction will do (vector shift right accumulate) :

```
vsra.u32 q0, q0, #31 // i += ((unsigned int) i) >> 31;
```

Note that it's `u32` on purpose and not `s32`.

NEON is easy to learn, but hard to master as you need to know many bit-hacking related techniques in order to write efficient codes like this which is many times faster than the traditional if-else approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do a compare and then subtract the result, since a `true` comparison result is equivalent to -1:

```
const int32x4_t vk0 = { 0 };

uint32x4_t vcmp = vcltq_s32(va, vk0);  // a < 0 ? 
va = vsubq_s32(va, (int32x4_t)vcmp);   // subtract -1 (i.e. add 1) for
                                       // each element where a < 0
```

If you want to do this at the assembly level then you can just use the following instructions:

- [vcltq_s32 ==> VCLT.S32](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472j/chr1360928367684.html)
- [vsubq_s32 ==> VSUB.I32](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491g/BABIBDGG.html)

Comment: Thanks Paul! I agree the above is a method to do the required. Is there any other way using NEON assembly instructions to do the same? For eg is it possible to use conditional instructions in NEON?

Comment: Sure - I've updated the question now to list the two instructions that you need.

Comment: Thanks Paul!! That works.. Just one small correction vcltq_s32 == VCLT.S32.